# How can I create a reference to an object to animate it in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, uibutton

I have an `imageView` and within it I put a button. I have two questions:

- How can I properly add a button without losing its functionality?
- How can I refer to my `imageView` within the method to animate the view?

The code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImageView *grayFrame = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"expSqrGray.png"]];

    [self.view addSubview:grayFrame];

    grayFrame.frame = CGRectOffset(grayFrame.frame, 0, 0);

    UIButton *testButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    testButton.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 200, 44);
    testButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [testButton setTitle:@"Test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [testButton addTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [grayFrame addSubview:testButton];
    //[self.view addSubview:testButton];
}
```

Comment: What kind of animation do you want to do?

Comment: Just move an image with a button from the bottom to a certain height.

Comment: Is it the button you want to animate? Or the image within the button?

Comment: I would like the same animation for both the image and the button. The image will act as a background and I will also add a label on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have little to no knowledge about Objective-C but what you probably want to do is to make `grayFrame` and `testButton` member variables of your class. That way, your whole class has access to those two objects.

For example:

```
// Test.H
@interface YourClass : NSObject {
   UIImageView * grayFrame;
   UIButton * testButton;
}
```

You can then have another method referring to either one of them.

```
- (void) initializeObjects {
   grayFrame = [ [ UIImageView alloc ] initWithImage:[ UIImage imageNamed:@"expSqrGray.png" ] ];
   testButton = [ UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom ];

   // Do things here.
}
```

Comment: Wow, how silly I am. I was so confused with all other things that I forgot about this. Thanks